# Log which Test Executor is running particular test?

Tags: testing, gradle, parallel-processing, executor

I configured my tests to run in `parallel`:

In my `build.gradle`:

```
test{
    maxParallelForks 2
    forkEvery 0
}
```

`./gradlew build --max-workers=8 --parallel`

But additionally I would like to know which executor is running particular test.

Is it possible to log such information?

I've tried to use `--debug` option but I doesn't appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the worker id is stored as system property and you can access it via within your test named `System.getProperty('org.gradle.test.worker')` from within your test.